# What is the cure for the illness of non patience or lack of patience?

Tags: quran, hadith, fiqh, islamic-philosophy

Selam aleikum. I have read many books on illnesses of heart like greed,jelosy,pride and their cures. But I have 0 information on curing the illness of non patience. Sometimes I feel I don't have patience even to read  ten pages of the Quran. Other times I feel I don't have patience to bear the presence of a leaf. QUESTION: What is the cure for the illness of non patience or lack of patience? Please advise me because as I said, I have 0 information on this issue. Please tell me every single thing that is useful or helpful on this issue.

Comment: Wailaikum musalam. For one, you can make dua to Allah: https://www.islamicfinder.org/duas/masnoon/for-patience/